# saving array into realm database swift

Tags: swift, realm

I have an application which uses realm database to persist data and everything works fine but the issue I have now is I want to save `photo: Data` array to the database and I tried using the standard swift array format but got an error at build time. below is my code

```
class TodoListModel: Object {

    @objc dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var photo: Data? = nil
    @objc dynamic var createdDate: Date?

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
    let parentCategory = LinkingObjects(fromType: CategoryModel.self, property: "items")

}
```

how do I now make the `photo` into an array

this is the way I create my List

```
func createTodoList(createdDate: Date, photo: Data) -> Void {

            let todoList = TodoListModel()
            todoList.createdDate = createdDate
            todoList.photo = photo
            TodoListFunctions.instance.addData(object: todoList)

    }
```

update model

```
func updateTodoList(update: TodoListModel, createdDate: Date, photo: Array<Data>) -> Void {
                    update.createdDate = createdDate
                    update.photo.append(objectsIn: photo)

    }
```

Comment: `photo` is of type `Data` at the moment, what do you want to change it to, `Array<Data>`?

Comment: I want to be able to sore more than one `photo` like selecting multiple photos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to store several objects of type `Data` in a single property of an `Object` subclass, you need to use `List`.

```
class TodoListModel: Object {

    @objc dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var createdDate: Date?
    let photos = List<Data>()
    let parentCategory = LinkingObjects(fromType: CategoryModel.self, property: "items")    

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

}
```

Then you can create a `TodoListModel` instance like this:

```
func createTodoList(createdDate: Date, photos: Array<Data>? = nil) -> Void {
    let todoList = TodoListModel()
    todoList.createdDate = createdDate
    if let photos = photos {
        todoList.photos.append(objectsIn: photos)
    }
    TodoListFunctions.instance.addData(object: todoList)
}
```

Comment: can this be null?

Comment: @King no, but there's no reason to make it `Optional` either. `photos `will be an empty `List` by default, so you can simply check `photos.count` to know if there are any photos attached to the `TodoListModel` or not, instead of checking against `nil`.

Comment: How do I now create my List. I updated the question with how I was creating the `photo` before.

Comment: @King check my updated answer. If there are no photos to add, simply call `createTodoList` like this: `func createTodoList(createdDate: Date())`, the `photos` input argument will default to `nil`.

Comment: The updated answer works but the problem now is if I want to update the photo i.e change the uploaded photo, appending a new object would just simply add a new photo data without replacing the old one

Comment: @King the `createTodoList` function is just there to create a new item. You can modify a `List` just like you would modify a normal Swift `Array`.

Comment: I know the create is just there to create and the update I wrote gave me error

Comment: If you show your update method I can help you correct it, but I think it would be best to discuss that in a new question, since this was specifically about saving an array of items to Realm, while modifying an existing collection in Realm is a different issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52761328/updating-an-array-of-items-in-realm-swift new question on updating