# updating an array of items in realm swift

Tags: swift, realm, realm-list

I am trying to update the content of a real database which takes an array. I would like to update the array stored in it below is my code for it

```
class TodoListModel: Object {

    @objc dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
    let photos = List<Data>()
    @objc dynamic var createdDate: Date?

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
    let parentCategory = LinkingObjects(fromType: CategoryModel.self, property: "items")

}
```

In this case, the new Data just gets added instead on replacing the previous one

```
func updateTodoList(update: TodoListModel, createdDate: Date, photo: Array<Data>) -> Void {
    update.createdDate = createdDate
    update.photo.append(objectsIn: photo)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all existing elements of `TodoListModel.photos` in your `updateTodoList` method, you simply need to call `update.photos.removeAll` before appending the contents of the `photos` input argument to it.

```
func update(todoList: TodoListModel, createdDate: Date, photos: Array<Data>) {
    todoList.createdDate = createdDate
    todoList.photos.removeAll()
    todoList.photos.append(objectsIn: photos)
}
```

P.S.: I've also renamed your function and its input arguments to match the Swift naming convention and the data that each input argument actually represents. There's also no need to write out the return value if your function is returning `Void`.

Comment: this would remove all the photo what If I just want to remove one of the photo

Comment: @King it's quite unclear what the `update` method should do in that case. Do you want to delete the last element of `todoList.photos` and add all elements from the input argument `photos`?

Comment: @King But how do you know what element is selected? There's nothing in your code signalling that an element would be selected. If you only want to update a single element, your function's type signature should look like this: `func update(todoList: TodoListModel, createdDate: Date, photo: Data, photoIndex: Int)`